# JAX-RS wildcard annotation

Tags: java, rest, annotations

EDIT: I have a not-thoroughly-tested answer below from a colleague, but I would still like to hear discussion and better answers.

I'll be happy to be pointed to an answer, but I haven't found it with my searches.

Java REST can be implemented with annotations of classes and methods, including @Path annotation to match URIs.  Is there an annotation, or other method, to match anything not explicitly matched by another annotation.  An example:

```
@Path("")
public class RestEntryPoint {

    @GET
    @Path("/{s:.*}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String anything(@Context UriInfo ui) {
        return "anything at all..." + ui.getPath();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/restserver/heartbeat")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String heartbeat() {
        return "Jetty RestServer heartbeat";
    }
}


http://localhost:8082/restserver/heartbeat/
```

... returns the correct text in a browser ("Jetty RestServer heartbeat").  But I want any other URI to respond with the message from the method `anything(@Context UriInfo ui)` - however I only receive a 404.

If this can be done some other way, please tell me how.  If this can be done this way (but differently) please show me the changes.

Comment: At the top of the file I think you have to add a slash to the path @Path("/")

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to map it to "/" explicitly and then let the method listen to ".*" or ".+":

```
@Path("/")
public class RestEntryPoint {

   @GET
   @Path("s:.*")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String anything(@Context UriInfo ui) {
       return "anything at all..." + ui.getPath();
   }

   @GET
   @Path("restserver/heartbeat")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String heartbeat() {
       return "Jetty RestServer heartbeat";
   }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This allows `localhost:8082` to map to `anything(...)`, but not any other URI.  I want ALL other URIs to map to `anything(...)`.

Comment: With jax-rs the most specific path is used. If I e.g. specify Path("/admin/{id}/redo") and Path("/admin/myspecificid/redo") it perfectly works and uses the "/admin/myspecificid/redo" in that case.

Comment: Now I gotcha. You need to specify @Path(".*") with the anything method. This is the a wildcard matching. If at least something should be specified use ".+"

Comment: that has not worked, but this does:
`@Path("")
public class RestEntryPoint {

 @GET
 @Path("/{s:.*}")
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
 public String anything(@Context UriInfo ui) {
  return "anything at all..." + ui.getPath();
 }
)`

Comment: Ok, I've changed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

just add a slash into the path.
like this

```
@Path("/")
 public class RestEntryPoint {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String anything(@Context UriInfo ui) {
    return "anything at all..." + ui.getPath();
}

@GET
@Path("/restserver/heartbeat")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String heartbeat() {
    return "Jetty RestServer heartbeat";
}
```

}

Comment: This allows `localhost:8082` to map to `anything(...)`, but not any other URI.  I want ALL other URIs to map to `anything(...)`.